# Locally (normal and $\mathfrak{X}$) groups II

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\mathfrak{X}$ be a class of group which is subgroup closed (namely $S\mathfrak{X}=\mathfrak{X}$, i.e. if $H\leq G$ and $G\in \mathfrak{X}$ then $H\in \mathfrak{X}$). Let $M\mathfrak{X}$ be the class of locally (normal and $\mathfrak{X}$)-groups. Let now $\overline{M}\mathfrak{X} :=\underset{\alpha}{\cup}{(M^{\alpha}\mathfrak{X}) }$, where $\alpha$ is an ordinal.

**Notations**

$\mathfrak{X}$ is a class of groups iff a trivial group belongs to $\mathfrak{X}$ and if a group $G$ belongs to $\mathfrak{X}$, then all isomorphic images of $G$ belongs to $\mathfrak{X}$.

$M^{\alpha+1}\mathfrak{X}=M(M^{\alpha}\mathfrak{X})$

$M^{\lambda}\mathfrak{X}=\displaystyle \bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}(M^{\alpha}\mathfrak{X})$ with $\lambda$ a limit ordinal

A group $G$ is said to be a "locally (normal and $\mathfrak{X}$)-group iff every finitely generated subgroup of $G$ is contained in a normal subgroup $H$ such that $H\in \mathfrak{X}$.

Let $G$ be a group and $X$ a subset of $G$, then by $X^G$ we meant the normal closure of $X$ in $G$ (i.e. the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ containing $X$).

**Problem**

I want to prove the following equivalence:

A group $G$ belongs to $\overline{M}\mathfrak{X}$ iff, given a descending series $G_1=G\geq G_2\geq...$  in which $G_{i+1}={X_i}^{G_i}\,(i=1,2,...)$ for some finite subset $X_i$ of $G_i$, there is a positive integer $n$ such that $G_n\in \mathfrak{X} $.

I cannot see why we can reduce to the integer case (namely why $n$ must be an integer). Any ideas about how to prove that?

**Partial solution**

If $G$ belongs to $\overline{M}\mathfrak{X}$, then $G$ belongs to an $M^{\alpha}\mathfrak{X}$ for a certain ordinal $\alpha$ and so by transfinite induction  we can prove the first part of the proposition.

Comment: What does it mean for a group to be locally normal (or $\mathfrak X$)? What do you denote by $X_i^{G_i}$? Are those topological groups? And what makes you think this is even true?

Comment: I think it's true because it is a "proposition" of D.J.S Robinson "Finiteness Conditions" (p. 62 of the first volume). They are not topological group. I edit the post to answer to your first observations.

Comment: You can of course take $G_2=\{e\}$, then you'll have $G\geq \{e\}$ and you'll get probably only that $\{e\}\in \mathfrak{X}$.

Comment: Okay, I understand now what I got wrong. I thought there's an existential quantifier there, not a universal one in the "Problem" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\Rightarrow)$: because successive $G_n$ belong to $M^{\alpha}\mathfrak X$ for smaller and smaller $\alpha$ and any descending sequence of ordinals is finite, so at some point we have $G_n,G_{n+1}\in M^\alpha\mathfrak X$ and $G_{n+1}\notin M^{\beta}\mathfrak X$ for $\beta<\alpha$. Since $G_{n+1}$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G_n$ containing a finite set, we must have $\alpha=0$ and we're done.

$(\Leftarrow)$: a proof by contraposition: take any $G$ which is not in $\overline M \mathfrak X$. Then it must have a finite subset which generates as a normal subroup a group $G_2\unlhd G$ which is not in $\overline M \mathfrak X$ (because otherwise $G$ would be locally (normal and $\overline M\mathfrak X$) which is just the same as $\overline M\mathfrak X$ by the construction). Applying this recursively we obtain a sequence witnessing that the RHS condition is false for $G$.

Comment: I'm sorry I've wasted your time: it was really easy, thanks :)

Comment: @W4cc0: don't mention it. Everyone gets stuck on trivialities from time to time.